# How to conduct repeated measures Anova when there are two within factors but I am only interested in the effect of one factor?

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, repeated-measures, experiment-design

For example, if my experimental design requires the subjects to participate in two identical sessions at two different time points(factor 1). In each session, the subjects go through all three conditions(factor 2) and the score for each condition is measured.

I am aware that if I want to account for both factors and their interaction, the code should be something like `aov(score~condition*timepoint + Error(subject/(condition*timepoint))`.

However, what if I am not interested in the effect of time, and the only reason that the participants are required to complete 2 sessions is to collect more data points? (Let's assume the performance won't improve over time). In this scenario, should I ignore this time factor and just do `aov(score~condition + Error(subject/condition)` which seems to be equivalent to having another group of participants, or should I do `aov(score~condition + Error(subject/(conition*timepoint)`, which seems to account for the time as a within group factor despite I am not treating it as an IV?

Thank you for your help, I am really confused

Comment: I guess one option would be to average scores (within condition) across the two time points and use the average scores as your dependent, if your research question allows this and if the within-condition scores are highly related. Another way would be to use multilevel regression and put in random intercept of subject and then just use condition as predictor. With lmer it would go lmer(score ~ (1|subject) + condition).

Comment: @Sointu Thank you for your answer! Do you know what an equivalent model to lmer(score ~ (1|subject) + condition) would be when using aov() method?

Comment: Possibly; I'm not familiar with the use of aov with stratified error terms (I tend to think of anova as either repeated-measures or between-subject ), but I guess the equivalent would be to use just condition as factor and just subject as source of error. But I'm not sure if this is OK. In lmer, you don't need to put time in as random or fixed effect if you aren't interested in time but I can't say for sure about aov.